# there is an error in the second for loop because of which program goes in a infinite loop. Can anybody help me please or point out my mistake?

Tags: c

second for loop because of which program goes in a infinite loop. Can anybody help me please or point out my mistake?

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
    int testcase;//no of trials
    scanf("%d",&testcase);
    int counter;
    for(counter=0;counter<testcase;counter++)
    {

        int options;
        scanf("%d",&options);

        int arri[options];
        int i;
        for(i=0;i<options;options++)//error:goes in a infinite loop i guess
        {
            scanf("%d",&arri[i]);

        }


        int sum=0;
        int limit;
        for(i=0;i<options;options++)
        {
            sum=sum+arri[i];
        }
        int marker;
        if((options%10)==0)
        {
            marker=options/10;
        }
        else
        {
            marker=options/10;
            marker++;
        }
        limit=(100+options-marker);
        if(sum<=limit && sum>=100)
        {
            printf("YES\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("NO\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Increment `i` not `options`

Comment: @Rizier that is the **answer**.

Comment: You could have answered this question yourself with simple debug outputs, e.g. output the value of i with printf ("%d\n", i); which would have shown you that i stays the same. Akternatively, use the debug mode of your IDE, i.e. set breakpoints, look at variables.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(i=0;i<options;options++)
```

you should change `options++` to `i++`

Answer (score 2):

```
 for(i=0;i<options;options++)
```

you have to increment i, not options

```
for(i=0; i<options; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you increment `options`

```
for(i=0;i<options;options++)
```

it will hold true that `i<options` forever *(or until overflow happens)*, the correct way could be

```
for(i=0;i<options;i++)
```